# How to delete data in Mysql using Php

Tags: php, sql, database, export

hello guys im having a hard time figuring how to delete data in database using php im using MYSQLI because mysql gives me warning i tried so many times but failed here is the code.HERE IS THE PICTURE:[PICTURE ERROR](http://prntscr.com/8oll8k)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
       .wrap{
           width:800px;
           margin:0px auto;

       }
      form{
          margin-left:200px;


      }
      a,a:visited{
          text-decoration:none;
          color:black;
      }
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    require('connect.php');
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
            $sid=$_POST['name'];
            $sql = "DELETE scholars ". "WHERE sid = $sid";
             $retval = $mysqli->query($sql,$mysqli );

            if(!$retval )
            {
               die('Could not delete data: ' . $mysqli->error);
            }

            echo "Deleted data successfully\n";

            $mysqli->close( );
         }  



    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <form action="dscholar.php" method="POST">
     <table>
        <tr>
        <td>ScholarID:</td> 
        <td><input type="text" name="name" required><td>
        </tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete Scholar"></td>
        <td><button><a href="index.html">Back to Homepage!</a></button></td>
        </tr>

     </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**HERE IS THE CONNECTION**

```
<?php
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","root","","dblogin");

?>
```

Comment: `"DELETE FROM scholars WHERE sid = $sid";`

Comment: care sharing the warning message?

Comment: you for got the `FROM`.... `delete from scholars where sid=$sid`

Comment: ^^ and no one knows what `". "` is surpose to be

Comment: shouldn't `$sid` be concatenated to the sql string?

Comment: @BurningCrystals no, the variable is interpolated since it's within double quotes

Comment: where is *"Here is the error..."*? couple of things wrong here.

Comment: I update it please see the ERROR

Comment: great, now we have to fetch an image of; post it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing `FROM` in your query

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM scholars WHERE sid = '$sid'";
```

and put variable inside `'`

```
'$sid'
```

Comment: i assumed anything with id in it is an integer but its from post name, so your most likely right there

Comment: i assumed as Dagon, good catch Shehary

Comment: then again the form says `ScholarID:` so who knows

Comment: There are always unknowns in questions, but from somewhere we have to start :)

Comment: possibly he is unaware of input type=number

Comment: ^^^bahhh html5 voodoo

Comment: [Si signore...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OEJh2FFUUoU) @Dagon

Comment: Honestly i even don't know there was HTML code, i just read the title and checked the query and wrote the answer, after 12 to 14 hours on SO I'm exhausted and up that is not an answer actually, am just want to go and watch The Flash new season :D

Comment: please see the warning picture that i posted

Comment: @orange18 this error is before or after the suggested changes in answer?

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS THE ANSWER AFTER SO MANY TRIES THIS IS IT I FORGOT THE FROM!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
       .wrap{
           width:800px;
           margin:0px auto;

       }
      form{
          margin-left:200px;


      }
      a,a:visited{
          text-decoration:none;
          color:black;
      }
    </style>    
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    require('connect.php');
        if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
            $sid=$_POST['name'];
            $sql ="DELETE FROM scholars ". "WHERE sid = $sid";
             if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: ";
}

$mysqli->close();

            }



    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
    <form action="dscholar.php" method="POST">
     <table>
        <tr>
        <td>ScholarID:</td> 
        <td><input type="number" name="name" required><td>
        </tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Delete Scholar"></td>
        <td><button><a href="index.html">Back to Homepage!</a></button></td>
        </tr>

     </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if ($mysqli->query($sql)` that... I knew. As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: *"Forgot the FROM"* - that isn't the only thing... `$mysqli->query($sql,$mysqli );`

Comment: well you could accept the othter dudes answer